# Sticky Footer Forced to Bottom on Short Page

Tags: css, sticky

Below is a very simple example of a problem I'm running into with a sticky footer. When the content of the page doesn't fill the viewport, the footer is treated like a statically positioned element. I realize this is technically the intended behavior of `position: sticky` but I'm wondering if there's a way to essentially force it to always be `position: fixed` in situations like this. I don't want to remove the element from the document flow, which is why I'm not just changing it to fixed permanently. Plus the page could have a variable height (based on content) so the sticky behavior would be needed if the page was longer than the viewport.

```css
html { height: 100%; }
body { min-height: 100%; }
.content {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.footer {
    position: sticky;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      Here is some sample content
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      This is the sticky footer
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will change the style of your footer based on the document height relative to the window height.

```
function init() {
    if (window.innerHeight < document.body.clientHeight) {
        document.querySelector(".footer").style.position = "sticky";
    }
    else {
        document.querySelector(".footer").style.position = "fixed";
    }

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: That will technically work if you remove the min-height I have on the body tag. Although I was hoping to avoid a JS solution and have it be pure CSS.